# Select Issue - Material Design Lite in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design-lite, angular2-mdl

I'm using Material Design lite: https://github.com/mseemann/angular2-mdl in angular2.

But I'm having some trouble with the select component with multiple. When you select items it appears on the top. Just like in the image bellow.

[Seletc component with itens selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gonu2.png)

I want to show the label or placeholder even when I select something.

HTML

```
<mdl-select  [(ngModel)]="cargosSelecionados" multiple="true" placeholder="Cargos">
                    <mdl-option mdl-ripple *ngFor="let cargo of cargos" [value]="cargo">{{cargo.nome}}</mdl-option>
                </mdl-select>
            </div>
```

I'm using the normal CSS from the github page.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take a look at this guide for asking a good Question: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/  Right now your question is at risk of being deleted as you haven't provided any of your own code attempts.